# X Y Z Rotation Angles to Direction Vector

Tags: vectors

Given 3 rotation angles (X Y Z), where:

Positive X makes the object rotate up (like a car doing a wheelie),
Positive Y makes the object rotate to the right (like a car driving only on the 2 right-side wheels),
Positive Z makes the object rotate counter-clockwise (to the left).

How do I calculate a direction vector off these 3 rotation angles? (They are in degrees, but I can convert them to radians if necessary).

Please if possible, I would like a direct math formula to do this, without the use of matrixes.

Comment: I have three bad news: 1) the order of application of the 3D rotations matters (the formulas are in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions); 2) had the $Y rotation been applied last, the formulas would have been simpler as the last rotation would have had no effect on the direction; 3) the matrix way is the simplest. (But for the direction, you just need one row of the matrix.)

Comment: Sorry for very late reply... I solved my issue with this already, thanks for your answer nevertheless! I found the math formulas I needed out of luck.

Comment: @Leon_Cliver could you post the formulas you found as an answer? Because I can't seem to find them anywhere.